# Staining and varnishing a new floor board to match the rest of the floor

Tags: flooring

Recently removed a wall between our lounge and dining rooms to create a nice big open space. I installed new raw floor boards in the hole where the wall was. The new floorboards are the same timber (cedar) as the rest of the house.

What is considered the best way to stain and varnish the new boards to match the rest of the flooring?

[image: new floorboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get close is to use a scrap piece of the lumber that was used in the repair, then test different stains/finishes until you get real close. From your picture, I would start with Minwax Golden Oak stain followed by clear water-based varnish.